# basic usage of service bus in website

Tags: c#, nservicebus

i'm making an asp.net website to support Json request.
Each request must send a message on a ESB (actually NServiceBus) but i'm struggling with response..

I can actually receive multiple request of same type so the website send similar messages of same type on the bus. How can I be sure that each message response from the bus goes to the exact "requester"?

How can I deal with slow or no bus response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the AsyncPages sample that comes with NSB. That demonstrates how you can use callbacks and the async support in asp.net to build robust message based communication from a website. Callbacks is there if you need to get a response back to the webserver that sent the request (command). It's often better to have the website only send messages off and then read the result from another data store (ravendb , sqlserver etc). That will give you the chance to get at the data even if the webserver goes down (callbacks are not persistent)